# Can't update pandas in Ubuntu server

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to update the pandas library since I made some html files that worked on a computer with features that came from the latest version of pandas, and when I uploaded the html files to my ubuntu server that is hosting the website, the pandas features obviously don't work.  I have pip 9.0.1 installed, and when I try to update pandas I get the following errors (sorry for the wall of code inc):

```
 Collecting pandas
   Downloading pandas-0.20.3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (22.4MB)
     99% |████████████████████████████████| 22.4MB 64.9MB/s eta 
 0:00:01Exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 
 215, in main
     status = self.run(options, args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", 
 line 335, in run
     wb.build(autobuilding=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in 
 build
     self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 
 380, in prepare_files
     ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 
 620, in _prepare_file
     session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, 
 in unpack_url
     hashes=hashes
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, 
 in unpack_http_url
     hashes)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 882,                               
 in _download_http_url
     _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 603,                                    
 in _download_url
     hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line                     
 46, in check_against_chunks
     for chunk in chunks:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 571, 
 in written_chunks
     for chunk in chunks:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, 
 in iter
     for x in it:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 560, 
 in resp_read
     decode_content=False):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 357, in 
 stream
     data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 314, in 
 read
     data = self._fp.read(amt)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 63, in read
     self._close()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 50, in _close
     self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 275, in 
 cache_response
     self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 87, in dumps
     ).encode("utf8"),
 MemoryError
```

Comment: Did you check if you have enough space left on your server?
You can try `pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade pandas`.

Comment: MemoryError means python has filled all RAM left (this is the only uncatchable error). You should stop processes that are heavy RAM consumers, make your update and then restart your processes.

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is full of heroes:

> Did you check if you have enough space left on your server? You can
> try pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade pandas. – Jan Zeiseweis
>
> MemoryError means python has filled all RAM left (this is the only uncatchable error). You should stop processes that are heavy RAM
> consumers, make your update and then restart your processes. –
> jlandercy

I did both of these at the same time, and it worked perfectly, and my website is running as expected again!